# UseNetTopologySuite on .NET 8

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-8.0

I am having some issues regarding .NET 8. Is it possible to use `UseNetTopologySuite` in .NET 8 ? It was working fine in .NET 7.

Here's my code:

```
var builder = new NpgsqlDataSourceBuilder(ConnectionString);
builder.UseNetTopologySuite();
using var connection = builder.Build().CreateConnection();
```

I get this error:

> Error CS1061
> 'NpgsqlDataSourceBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseNetTopologySuite' and no accessible extension method 'UseNetTopologySuite' accepting a first argument of type 'NpgsqlDataSourceBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Thanks

I try upgrade or installing again the following Nuget packages:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5EZb.png)

Comment: Works just fine for me. Do you have a [mre] which you can post somewhere like github?

Comment: what are the Nuget packages that you are using ?

Comment: The last one from your screenshot as far as I remember